# Getting Column from Joined Subtable in LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, datagridview

I don't know how to access the value from a subtable "Produkt"

[image]

I have a datagridview which uses the Datasource from the LINQ result from the picture.

The columns from maintable are displayed correctly, but for the subtable "Produkt" I can't reach the Name Column value.

If I Use "Produkt" in the DataPropertyName the Result is:

```
{ContainerDB.tbl_Produkt}
```

with Produkt.Name nothing is displayed.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a cheat if you will, but if you override .ToString on the Produkt class to return the value of the name property it should display the Name instead of the class info.

You could also put a property on the class that has the produkt in it.  Something like:

```
Public Readonly Property ProduktName() as String
    Get
       Return Produkt.Name
    End Get
End Property
```